# JavaScript saving HTML in a variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm currently trying to save some HTML (which comes from an XML file) in a variable, but somehow i get some strange errors. In addition to that, it seems that the browser tries to load the images used in that piece of HTML code, even if I don't use it.

Here's the code:

```
// Load the data from the XML node.
var description = $(this).find('description').text();

var descriptionWithTags = description.replace('<p>','');
descriptionWithTags = descriptionWithTags.replace('</p>','########');

// Remove HTML Tags and add the Line-Breaks
var convertedString = $(descriptionWithTags).text();
convertedString = convertedString.replace('########','<br /><br />');
console.log("E");

// Save it in an array.
contentRSS[articleCount] = convertedString;
```

Edit: If i remove the following line, it works again, but I don't now why.

```
descriptionWithTags = descriptionWithTags.replace('<p>','');
```

Comment: ...and what are these elusive `strange errors` ?

Comment: It says that there's a error in jquery.js, but show's me part of the loaded html content. It looks like, as it is mixing up something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with a text without HTML tags :

```
var description = $(this).find('description').text(); // this removes HTML tags
```

then you try to parse it as HTML :

```
var convertedString = $(descriptionWithTags).text();
```

This can't work. You should probably use html in the first line :

```
var description = $(this).find('description').html();
```

Comment: Hello, thank's for you answer. I'm not sure, but i think i need the second .text() as it removes the html tags. The first .text() just removes the <![... ]]> of the loaded contend. Here's a sample of the note. <description>
<![CDATA[ some HTML Code goes here.
]]>
</description>

Comment: The problem is mainly in the first one : you can't ask for raw text (purged from HTML tags) and then ask it to be interpreted as HTML.